# Android Studio Weird Warning

Tags: android, android-support-library, appcompatactivity

After I updated my Support library from `23.1.1` to `23.4.0` I get this warning `cannot access android.support.v4.app.baseFragmentActivityEclair` on every call to super and every instance of `AppCompatActivity`

And if I updated my support library to `24.1.1` The warning changes to `cannot access android.support.v4.app.baseFragmentActivityJB`.

Can anyone tell me why this warning is shown and how can I remove this warning:

here is my dependencies before:
(no error in this)

```
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
```

here is my dependencies after `cannot access android.support.v4.app.baseFragmentActivityEclair`warning:

```
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
```

here is my dependencies after `cannot access android.support.v4.app.baseFragmentActivityJB`warning:

```
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
```

Comment: What is your android.defaultConfig.minSdkVersion ? I assume that google has dropped Fragment support for older android versions. (i.e. android-Eclair(api 5...7)) in newer versions. setting minSdkVersion=8 should eleminate the "baseFragmentActivityEclair" error.

Comment: i am using minsdk = 14

Answer (score 2):

We ran into a similar problem when one of the packages in our project had dependencies on version 24.0 support libraries and another package was dependent on version 23.4.0. This seems to be a problem for the Android Studio (IntelliJ) IDE, not the compiler, because we were able to build and run the project without any problems. We resolved the warning by reverting the 24.0 dependency to 23.4.0. I suspect that going the other direction (advancing all of our package dependencies to 24.0) would also have eliminated the warning but we didn't experiment with that due to the number of packages in our project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to hack around this, many of the support libraries have an internal library called `libs/internal_impl-$VERSION.jar` that includes these types of version-specific implementations.  To get your IDE to work, you can extract these JARs and manually include them in your IDE's build path.

For example, you can extract the classes referenced here, assuming version 24.2.1, using this command:

```
unzip support-fragment-24.2.1.aar libs/internal_impl-24.2.1.jar
```